# Subsequent npm operations encounter permission issues

Tags: laravel, npm, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I realize that there are numerous other questions like this. I've tried all the solutions but to no avail, this is driving me up the walls.

**My issue**
Just a standard `npm install`, `npx mix` or `npm install <package>` in a Laravel 8 folder. Basically any npm operation.
I get this error (the package may vary, it's not relevant to that):

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path .../@ungap/promise-all-settled
npm ERR! dest .../@ungap/.promise-all-settled.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '.../@ungap/promise-all-settled' -> '.../@ungap/.promise-all-settled.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I've replaced the absolute paths with ellipses.

**My attempted solutions**

- I've re-installed node and npm with nvm (everything is at it's shiny latest version)
- I've created this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -d node_modules ]] && rm node_modules -rf
[[ -e package-lock.json ]] && rm package-lock.json
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/$USER/.npm"
npm install
```

**My observations**
This is a permissions issue. When I restart my system (not merely close and reopen a WSL console window) npm functions fine with any first operation. Then it's the same all over again. Could there be a package that modifies permissions somewhere? And even then, my script above doesn't fix the issue.

This is a massive irritation. Any help would be equally massively appreciated. Thanks.

edit: added backticks to npm examples